# Visual Studio 2012 template project "macros" are evaluated incorrectly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a template C# project for Visual Studio 2012. In the Project/ItemGroup/Compile attribute of the template, whenever I use a "macro" (e.g. `$(SolutionDir)`) it evaluates incorrectly to a temporary folder (e.g. '%TEMP%\fsiqkcs.kiu').

Here is the xml for my template:

```
<Compile Include="$(SolutionDir)AssemblyInfoShared.cs">
    <Link>Properties\AssemblyInfoShared.cs</Link>
</Compile>
```

And this is what it evaluates to when used to create a new project:

```
<Compile Include="..\..\..\..\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Temp\fsikqkcs.kiu\AssemblyInfoShared.cs">
    <Link>Properties\AssemblyInfoShared.cs</Link>
</Compile>
```

I have tried surrounding `$(SolutionDir)` in single quotes (i.e. `'$(SolutionDir)'AssemblyInfoShared.cs`, and substituting for a custom parameter, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wba5h42(v=vs.110).aspx - neither of these make a difference.

Comment: Can you check in project's Properties>Build Events>Edit Pre-Build>Macros what they evaluate to? It looks like something is wrong with your installation.

Comment: I can check that tomorrow, but I wouldn't expect it to be a problem as elsewhere in the project file they seem to work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please disregard my comment.

I created a simple project with a link:

```
 ...
 <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Test.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="$(SolutionDir)Test2.cs" />
 </ItemGroup>
 ...
```

In the .vstemplate file of the exported project template I set [CreateInPlace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247196%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to true:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>TemplateProj</Name>
    <Description>&lt;No description available&gt;</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>TemplateProj</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
    <CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="TemplateProj.csproj" File="TemplateProj.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <Folder Name="Properties" TargetFolderName="Properties">
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="AssemblyInfo.cs">AssemblyInfo.cs</ProjectItem>
      </Folder>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Test.cs">Test.cs</ProjectItem>
    </Project>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

And that seemed to fix it. It's weird since the documentation states that the default value for `CreateInPlace` is true.